# Codesynthesis - Compare string value with sequence in C++

Tags: c++, compare, sequence, codesynthesis

I'm new to Codesynthesis and i'm wondering about how i can compare string values with a sequence.

For example i have a Message id "0x100" and i want to check if its in the Send sequences. If its there, i just want to get the Signal name of the Message with the id "0x100" (in this case: "one") and not the whole sequence.

With my code i can get all the Message ids in all Send sequences, but i dont know how to use them to compare it to a string variable respectively just get one element out of the sequence and save it to a string variable.

How can i accomplish this?

Thanks for your help!

This is the xml:

```
<record>
  <signals>
    <Send name="Port1">
        <Message id="0x100">
            <Signal name="one"/>
        </Message>
        <Message id="0x101">
            <Signal name="two"/>
            <Signal name="three"/>
            <Signal name="four"/>
        </Message>
        <Message id="0x102">
            <Signal name="five"/>
        </Message>
        <Message id="0x103">
            <Signal name="six"/>
        </Message>
        <Message id="0x104">
            <Signal name="seven"/>
            <Signal name="eight"/>
            <Signal name="nine"/>
            <Signal name="ten"/>
        </Message>
        <Message id="0x105">
            <Signal name="eleven"/>
        </Message>
    </Send>
    <Send name="Port2">
        <Message id="0x106">
            <Signal name="twelve"/>
        </Message>
        <Message id="0x107">
            <Signal name="thirteen"/>
        </Message>
        <Message id="0x108">
            <Signal name="fourteen"/>
        </Message>
        <Message id="0x109">
            <Signal name="fifteen"/>
        </Message>
        <Message id="0x110">
            <Signal name="sixteen"/>
        </Message>
    </Send>
  </signals>
</record>
```

This is how i read the sequences from the xml:

```
string filename = "test.xml";
unique_ptr<record> h(record(filename));

signals::Send_sequence& s(h->signals().Send());
for (signals::Send_iterator i(s.begin()); i != s.end(); ++i)
{
        Send::Message_sequence& s2(i->Message());
        for (Send::Message_iterator j(s2.begin()); j != s2.end(); ++j)
        {
            Message& u(*j);
            cout << u.id() << endl;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: I found the solution. It was quite easy.

```
string filename = "test.xml";
unique_ptr<record> h(record(filename));

signals::Send_sequence& s(h->signals().Send());
for (signals::Send_iterator i(s.begin()); i != s.end(); ++i)
{
        Send::Message_sequence& s2(i->Message());
        for (Send::Message_iterator j(s2.begin()); j != s2.end(); ++j)
        {
            Message& u(*j);
            cout << u.id() << endl;

            //Check if theres a message
            if (u.id().present()) {

            //Put the message in a struct array (same with signals)
            info[NumberOfSends].messages[NumberOfMessages] = u.id().get(); //this is how you get it as a string
            NumberOfMessages++;
            }

        }

}NumberOfSends++;
```

Now you can use this array to compare it to a string.